# Failed connections from AT&T cellular to Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase

For the last 48h or so, we have had users on AT&T cellular in the US reporting connectivity issues with our mobile Firebase application. We've narrowed the problem down to Cloud Functions: users on AT&T cellular cannot connect to our Cloud Functions endpoints. They can connect just fine when using a WiFi network.

We have asked some users to run traceroutes to our endpoint from their devices, and the hops are oddly going through the European Union, with some significant (>20%) loss on the last hop.

I'm hoping others can confirm what we're seeing. Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

Comment: Yes! I'm having the same issue with AT&T. Let me know if you find any answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is too localised in both space and time.

Comment: @nachshonf GCP support narrowed the issue down to the Cloud Function IPv6 VIP not being properly configured in their front proxy. This was being compounded by AT&T's transparent proxy accepting the connection to the non-existent IP, then closing the session when that failed, breaking the OS' fallback to IPv4. Google reverted the DNS change, and this resolved the issue for our affected users.